# Real life color to RGB

Tags: javascript, node.js, rgb, color-space, cmyk

I have array of square regions which covered with 5 colors CMYK +white. There is no overlap of colors. When you looking at those squares from distance - each square become 1 pixel. I need to convert each square to closest RGB equivalent and create an image. I can get percentage of each color, in JSON file. Can use javascript on client side or on server side.

Example of input:

```
[
    {c:20,m:10,y:15,k:20,w:35}, // Percent of area covered by color
    {c:50,m:0,y:0,k:0,w:50},
    ...
]
```

Expected output:

```
[
    {r:?,g:?,b:?},
    {r:?,g:?,b:?},
    ...
]
```

Comment: It seems like you're trying to convert CMYK to RGB, which [has been asked and answered before](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37641733/215552).

Comment: Not exactly. I have percentage of CMYKW - I don't know how to convert 30% white 20% Black 50% Cyan - into CMYK - to convert it into RGB

Comment: I've never heard of having both K and W, considering K is the amount of black and I would think W would just be the opposite. Don't know what to tell you. I'd do more digging on the internet. For instance, I found [this table](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/US7583421B2/US07583421-20090901-D00006.png) within a patent application, but I have no clue if it's accurate or really anything about it.

Comment: Usually you get CMYK for mixed color - so K is portion of black, but in my case it is not mixed color - so black and white is part of mixture which must be calculated into K. Also I don't know how to calculate CMY parts. For example does 50% cyan and 50% white - means C = 0.5 or C = 1 ?

Comment: it sounds like each square is just pure cyan magenta yellow black, so those 4 colors directly in rgb are just cyan:rgb(0,255,255), yellow:rgb(255,255,0), magenta: rgb(255,0,255), black: rgb(0,0,0)